# Julia - Transform a matrix to a vector

Tags: arrays, performance, matrix, vector, julia

Appart from allocating a new vector and filling its values one by one with the one of my matrix, how would I resize / refill a matrix of size `n x m` to a vector of size `n x m` generalizing the following example:

```
julia> example_matrix = [i+j for i in 1:3, j in 1:4]
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  3  4  5
 3  4  5  6
 4  5  6  7

julia> res_vect = [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]
12-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 3
 4
 5
 4
 5
 6
 5
 6
 7
```

An idea I had is:

```
 res_vect = Int[]
 for j in 1:size(example_matrix,2)
    res_vect = vcat(res_vect, example_matrix[:,j])
 end
```

I have the feeling it is not the optimal way yet I could not explain why...

Comment: BTW, never initialize a vector with `res_vect = []`, unless you have a very good reason. `[]` creates a `Vector{Any}`, which will poison the other arrays you concatenate it with. Writing `[]` is a _huge_ red flag for performance. You should write `Int[]` if you intend the array to contain `Int`s.

Comment: Thanks @DNF, I didn't know :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julia allows you to do that sort of thing even without copying any data:

```
julia> m = [i+j for i in 1:3, j in 1:4]
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 2  3  4  5
 3  4  5  6
 4  5  6  7

julia> m1 = vec(m)  # m1 points to the same memory address as m
12-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3
 4
 3
 4
 5
 4
 5
 6
 5
 6
 7

julia> m2 = reshape(m, 4, 3) # m2 still points to the same memory address as m
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 2  4  6
 3  5  5
 4  4  6
 3  5  7
```

If you are wondering what "points to the same memory address" means have a look at this example:

```
julia> m2[1,1] = -66         
-66                          
                             
julia> m                     
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:           
 -66  3  4  5                
   3  4  5  6                
   4  5  6  7
```

Finally, if at any point you actually need a copy rather than a reference to the same data use `copy(m)` or as commented by @DNF `m[:]` (this is a dimension drop operator that returns a `Vector` with copy of data from any `Array`).

Comment: To get a vector, using copying, one can just write `y = x[:]`.

Comment: Wow, there is a simple function for what I want! Thanks ;)